# Loading images from listbox to picturebox

Tags: c#, listbox, picturebox

I'm trying to load .JPEG images from a directory and into a `ListBox` by a button click, which I have achieved. However, I need to take these images and put them into a `PictureBox`. Could someone please point me in the right direction? This is what i have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\cake");

        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(@"C:\cake");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] x = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\cake", "*.jpeg");
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look more like...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\cake");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.jpeg");
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(Files);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fi.FullName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for it is how to display an image in a picture box using the images location.

```
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation("Image Location");
```

If you want the user to be able to select the image try something like this.

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "JPEG FILES(*.jpeg)";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation(dlg.FileName.ToString());
        }
```